# My trivia is too broad?

Tags: discussion

[Is it the crown that makes the king or, is it his throne?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66098/45481)

I do not understand how a question with a specific answer can be too broad?

Admittedly, the answerers so far have guessed or, used inaccurate reference material or material upon which their own inferences have been incorrect.

If there were a `misdirection` tag I may have been able to use it. (yes, this is a hint for meta readers!) - which is what makes the riddle tag appropriate IMHO by its definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close reasons like "too broad" are inherently subjective, and I wasn't one of the close voters, but I can offer my opinion (there's also more generalised discussion elsewhere on meta if you search for it)...

> I do not understand how a question with a specific answer can be too broad?

A puzzle becomes too broad when there are multiple, equally valid answers that seem correct (in the sense that they seemingly fulfil the criteria of the puzzle as given), but aren't (but only because the poster said so, not because of anything inherently wrong about them).

> Admittedly, the answerers so far have guessed or, used inaccurate reference material or material upon which their own inferences have been incorrect.

If you provide no "reference material" of your own, then people are left to make there own inferences. If they do, and your puzzle doesn't invalidate those inferences with other clues, then those answers aren't strictly wrong, just not what you intended. The onus is on the puzzle creator to restrict the clues in such a way that, once found, a single answer is obviously correct. Failing to do so causes the puzzle to devolve into a game of "guess what I'm thinking".

---

Now, to address your particular puzzle more specifically, there's a couple of things you could do, depending on what you intend (without knowing the solution, it's hard to say which is the most appropriate path to take):

1. Add more detail/clues to restrict the range of possible solutions to your intended one and rule out what would otherwise make plausible/valid guesses.
2. You *do* actually provide some "extra information" in your riddle (namely the ascii art), but you also imply that it's extraneous. If it's not, then the current answers are mostly invalidated and your riddle is probably not overly broad. If that's the case, I'd suggest removing your meta-commentary and perhaps adding [visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) to make clearer that the art should be factored into the answer.
3. Finally, it's worth noting that a puzzle *can* still have multiple "technically correct" solutions and *not* be too broad. But *if and only if*, the intended solution *clearly* stands out as being genuinely better and *obviously* correct, once presented. This is rare in my experience, but if you honestly believe it to be the case here, you could edit in a note/plea to reviewers and hope that your puzzle is reopened as is. Just be aware that this approach is a long shot that requires trust on the part of reviewers, and you're probably better off following the advice in the first two points, regardless.
4. **EDIT**: I've just noticed you're using the [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia) tag, and seeing your comment/edit has made me realise that my prior points may have failed in one major assumption... That your puzzle is in fact a riddle at all, rather than just a trivia question. If your puzzle is literal, and your question is effectively, "What designates a person as king in English custom?", then it sounds like it shouldn't be tagged [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) in the first place, leaving it as a pure trivia question. This type of question is [off topic anyway](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/trivia/info), and there's not much you can do to reverse the closure other than completely reworking the puzzle into something more substantial.

Comment: I did mention that it was quite literal, however, I did not mention that it was misdirection to offer the two possibilities. I will re-frame the question and add a bit and see what happens. Thank you.

Comment: @Willtech - See my edit above...